# err no such file or directory - go file uploader - when i run binary of (go build)

Tags: go, file-upload, build, go-gin

i have below uploader

```
func SaveFile(c *gin.Context) {
    // Source
    file, err := c.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("get form err: %s", err.Error()))
        return
    }

    filename := filepath.Base(file.Filename)
    if err := c.SaveUploadedFile(file, "upload/"+filename); err != nil {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, fmt.Sprintf("upload file err: %s", err.Error()))
        return
    }

    c.String(http.StatusOK, fmt.Sprintf("File %s uploaded successfully with fields ", file.Filename))
}
```

and this static route in main.go

```
    server.Static("/upload", "./upload")
```

this codes works fine when I run `go run main.go` 
but
it is not working when I run binary of `go build` and I receive below error:

```
upload file err: open upload/updateprofile.png: no such file or directory
```

structure of my folders is as bellow:
[image]

and systemctl service is as bellow:
[image: service]

Comment: I don't think `go run build` is valid, unless `build` is the name of a package, or the name of a go source file. Can you show the exact commands that you're executing? And can you show *where from* you're executing them? By "where from" I mean which directory, since you're using a relative path as the root of the static files the location from which you're executing the binary is important.

Comment: @mkopriva
thanks for your response, sorry i had typo
i use ```go build ``` to create binary from my project , and with service that i created with  systemctl i run that binary .
when you execute ```go  build ``` it will give you binary with name of your go-module

Comment: So the problem seems to me to be the fact that the systemctl's `cwd` is different from your own when you run `go run main.go`. The `"upload/"+filename` and `"./upload"` are both relative paths and will be resolved based on the `cwd` of the running process. So to fix it you need to make sure to provide an absolute paths, instead of a relative ones, or you need to tell systemctl to `cd` before executing the binary.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks alot , i update my question and add pic of systemctl service , i wonder if you tell me how to add cd before that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `gin` API does not create the folders for you https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/c7a28f85320125709e47c592a92421a4d6f192a7/context.go#L579

Comment: @mh-cbon 
i do not want ```gin``` to create folder for me , i had upload folder , please look at  the pic of my directories

Comment: the setup of this folder has to be part of your deployment pipeline or service definition or the startup sequence of your app to ensure it is set. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354583/how-to-automatically-create-a-runtime-folder-with-a-systemd-service-or-tmpfiles

Comment: @tp-lovers if you're just executing this on your local machine then try updating your systemctl `[Service]` configuration by adding `WorkingDirectory=<path_to_parent_directory_of_upload_folder>`.

Comment: @mkopriva hi , when I check  the upload folder I understand , in both build mode and binary  , I receive message that "File uploaded successfully" but it is not in upload folder :[

Comment: @mkopriva  i use absolute path either in this part
```c.SaveUploadedFile(file, "/home/saeed/go/src/crmbackend/upload/" +filename)```
but again it says "file uploaded successfully " but it is not uploaded

Comment: @tp-lovers then maybe `SaveUploadedFile` is not the right thing for what you're trying to do. But I can't help you more than that because I don't use gin at all.

Comment: @tp-lovers but looking at its [source](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/v1.7.2/context.go#L577) it looks pretty straightforward and I'm not sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: @mkopriva i change chown of upload directory now , but it doesnot help and file again does not uploaded

Comment: @mh-cbon  hi, i wonder if you can help  , when I check the upload folder I understand , in both build mode and binary , I receive message that "File uploaded successfully" but it is not in upload folder :[ 
 i use absolute path either in this part  ```c.SaveUploadedFile(file, "/home/saeed/go/src/crmbackend/upload/" +filename) ```  but again it is not in upload folder :

Comment: @tp-lovers can you make a reprducible and small example. Declarng main, router, handler, a little web form, then post a new question. So we can sort this out; their must be a good reason to explain as to what happen

Comment: @mh-cbon sure thanks